# Stop Tables Expanding? HTML Table Rows and Data

Tags: html, html-table

Might be a basic question. I have a table, for instance 2x2.
It has a height and width set. When I enter a lot of text into one, it will shrink the box next to it. Even though theres loads of room! I want both rows (boxes) to stay the same size!

[image: See This]
Thanks!

```
<table style="height: 190px; width: 896px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Co-ordSport NL</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">Solvayweg 15a</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">6049 CP Herten, Netherlands</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">+31 (0)475 772719</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;Co-ordSport DE</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">Oberstraße 35</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">56332 Alken, Germany</p>
                <p style="text-align: center;">+49 (0)2605 408 9946</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... you can just asign the height/width to each td instead of the table :)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly define each td as having width 50% (or whatever width you want) and it will not resize like that.